# Disclosure indicator disappeared on the all storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

I was experimenting to add a gradient to the cells of a tableView and so, to have it show smoothly, I changed some settings in the viewController. Unfortunately, while experimenting, the (i) for the disclosure indicator all but disappeared, both in the view controller I was working on, and in all the others for the storyboard! Strangely the iPad storyboard was left unchanged. If I try to recover the backup of the storyboard I have a crash on the viewController I was working on and I would rather not recover the full project, if possible. What could it be? It is a bug or an unknown feature? And what option should I check to reenable it?
Doing it in the code with:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

does nothing new.
[image: Storyboard with no disclosure]

Comment: As a matter of fact I recovered the backup and the i were back again and I will have to rebuild something. So I tried to set: cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; in order to show the gradient in the full cell, and again the i disappeared, albeit this time just in that single view controller. Is it possible that that marker is part of the background?

Comment: And what is even stranger is that even removing the command the i keep not showing, like if the view were corrupted. Cleaning the project and even deleting the app from the iPhone solves nothing. I am afraid I will have to recover the project again from the backup.

Comment: Even recovering the project this time did not fix it. Now I deleted the app from the iPhone and recover the backup again. This situation is getting creepy.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to a quite old backup and did not try to change the background again, and it works.